# Add User Settings at runtime in a c# application

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, settings

I want to add new settings to the user.config at runtime for a C# application (WPF).
These settings will be added by independent modules so I have no idea what they will be in advance.

Most examples refer to:

```
Configuration config =
    configurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

But this only allows you to access the Application Settings
and you can't save it anyway as it's not meant to be modified.

I want to be able to do something like

```
Settings.Default.Add("SomeKey", "someobject");
Settings.Default.Save()
```

after which this setting would be available the next time this specific user
starts the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to check [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/user_settings.aspx).

It is doable but it is lots of code.

Comment: I guess it's easier to simply save an XML file in the Local App directory then for what I'm trying to do